# No carga los js usando archivos estáticos en ASP .NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net

Estoy intentando levantar un sitio en Angular 2 usando archivos estáticos con ASP .NET Core 2.

La compilacion de Angular lo hago por consola, publicando todo en wwwroot.

Luego invoque el método UseStaticFiles dentro de Startup.Configure para que lea los archivos estaticos dentro de la carpeta "wwwroot".

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Al correrlo el archivo index carga bien pero los al cargar los archivos js me devuelve el mismo html. Es acá donde no entiendo porque hace eso.

[image: Captura]

Cualquier ayuda servirá.

Gracias

Comment: Es lo único que tenes en el Configure?

Comment: Si, sólo necesito que cargue los archivos tal cual estan en la carpeta wwwroot